# How to serialize from javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, x-www-form-urlencoded

Have a example object:

```js
data = {
    var1: 'val 1',
    var2: 'val 2'
}
```

Hot to transform to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content?, with jquery transform only from form objects but not from javascript objects.

The expect: `var1=val+1&var2=val+2`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to iterate over the object:

`Object.keys(data).map(x=>x+'='+data[x]).join('&').replace(/ /g,'+')`

Result:

`var1=val+1&var2=val+2`